# How can I access the polling setting in the source filter/transformers?

Tags: java, object, mirth

**as a short background:**
I wrote a channel that imports certain files from my server as bas64 encoded strings into the CONFIGURATION database as a backup strategy.
I also added a destination to retrieve those files from the database and restore them into a local directory.
The channel should poll automatically once every night, to backup the files and should be polled manually to backup or restore the files, if necessary.

**My problem:**
I need a way to distinguish whether the channel polles automatically or manually.
If it's polled automatically (e.g. at night) the destination for restoring the files should not be executed.
If it's polled manually, the selected destination should be executed.

I know I can remove the restoring destination from the destinationSet but if I do so without any condition, the destination (of course) won't be executed, even if directly selected in the dashboard.

I thought about inserting an if-statement, that checks if the current time equals the time, that's set in the polling settings.
Of course I could just type the timestamp in manually into the transformer, but that way I would need to adjust it twice if the polling time should be changed.
Is there a way to get infomation about the polling settings in the source filter/transformer?

thank you in advance :)

I tried disabling the restoring destination, but this way you'd have to disable it and redeploy the channel every time you want to use the restoring destination.

I put an if statement into the source transformers, that removes all destinations except the backup destination if the current hour and minute equals the hour and minute defined in two dedicated global channel map variables. ('auto_poll_hour' and 'auto_poll_minute')
For now these two variables need to be filled by hand.

I tried using Packages.com.mirth.connect.donkey.model.channel.CronProperty().getExpression()
as well as Packages.com.mirth.connect.donkey.model.channel.PollConnectorProperties.getPollingHour()
and Packages.com.mirth.connect.donkey.model.channel.PollConnectorProperties.getPollingMinute() but it gives me the error message, that those methods wouldn't exist even though they seem to be public methods.

My colleague said I may need to generate an instance of some object in the mirth repository first and then access possible methods, but for now I couldn't find a suitable one.
I found the "donkey" class, which can be accessed via getInstance() but this seems to be an overall object for the mirth connect installation and not for the channel.

Comment: Could you make it be a file reader that polls at your time for a "dummy" text file that has the string "auto" in it, and to manually fire off the code you just use the built in message send tool in Mirth and put "manual"?   I'm sure theres a more correct way, but thats my initial thought.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, thank you! I'll give it a try and let you know!

Comment: I tried this and it works smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just want to know when the channel is being polled because of the "Poll Once on Start:" option. Every other poll will be due to scheduled events.

There doesn't seem to be an obvious variable/indicator to know why a poll event is happening, but you can use a global channel variable (visible to that channel).

Try adding something like this to your channel's Deploy script.

```
// Flag to know we just deployed.
globalChannelMap.put('NEW_DEPLOY',true)
return;
```

And something like this in your script that runs during a poll request.

```
if ($gc('NEW_DEPLOY') == true) {
    logger.info("NEW_DEPLOY WAS " + $gc('NEW_DEPLOY') + ", POLL ON DEPLOY")
    globalChannelMap.put('NEW_DEPLOY',false)
} else {
    logger.info("NEW_DEPLOY WAS " + $gc('NEW_DEPLOY') + ", SCHEDULED POLL")
}
```

Let us know if that works.

Comment: Hello, that's not exactly what I need. In the dashboard you can trigger the channel via "Send Message" or selecting a Message and "Resend Message". You can do that without redeploying the channel.